# Why are my TCDL Tags not converted to XPM markup?

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, upgrade, tcdl

After upgrading a 2013 GA environment to 2013 SP1 I am trying the new TCDL syntax for marking fields (`<tcdl:Field/>` and `<tcdl:FieldValue/>`). The problem is that this syntax does not get converted into the XPM comment/JSON syntax by my templates. Digging deeper in the template builder, I can see that the Enable Inline Editing for Content TBB does not process these tags, and then they are removed by the Cleanup Template TBB. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should upgrade your existing Default Templates by opening Template Builder, choosing `Tools | Create Default Building Blocks` from the menu, and selecting the **parent folder** for the "Default Templates" folder in the relevant parent Publication. For instance, if your default templates are in "Building Blocks\Templates\Default Templates", you need to choose "Building Blocks\Templates".

Comment: Thanks Peter - I couldnt find this step in the documentation - is it in there? Is this just needed for the XPM TBBs, or are there others that get upgraded (the 'normal' ones refer to an assembly in the GAC if I remember correctly)

Comment: @WillPrice I seem to be missing this info in the documentation indeed, there is a mention about it not being done by the installer though [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3DC3F706-DF37-46DE-B7E7-AD026943ED06) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

Comment: I guess it might be missing from the upgrade documentation, but it's certainly not just XPM TBBs. It updates any of the TBBs that have registered themselves in the defaultTemplatesScripts section of Tridion.ContentManager.config; Outbound E-mail and SmartTarget are two that spring to mind.

Comment: also the ECL TBBs are upgraded (2013 GA contains two and 2013 SP1 contains 1 new one, named Resolve ECL Items V2, which is using the same code as my example TBB [here](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/ECL%20TBB/trunk/ECL%20Template%20Building%20Blocks/ResolveEclItems.cs))

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the upgrade process does not upgrade the `Tridion.SiteEdit.Templating` TBB - this is needed for the new tags to be interpreted. You need to manually do this, by opening the TBB, and uploading the upgraded `Tridion.SiteEdit.Templating.dll` (which can be found in [tridioninstallroot]/bin

Comment: Since you could have multiple locations where you have the default TBBs, the upgrade process indeed doesn't do this for you. But as [Peter explains](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/why-are-my-tcdl-tags-not-converted-to-xpm-markup/3814#3814), you can just use the Template Builder for this.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, it didn't work because you need to start a field marker before you start a field value marker. Here a sample

```
@@FieldStartMarker("FieldName")@@
    @@FieldValueStartMaker("FieldName")@@
        @@GetFieldValue("FieldName")@@
    @@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
@@FieldEndMarker()@@
```

I was following a sample with this content.

```
// Wrong    
@@FieldValueStartMaker("FieldName")@@
    @@GetFieldValue("FieldName")@@
@@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
```