# Web 8 - XPM markup not appearing in published pages

Tags: experience-manager, web8

I have recently installed web 8 and trying to setup XPM on my website as per [doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-E7D54121-70A2-4FA6-A516-8ADB8E45AC13).

XPM markup is not appearing on the published pages, however if I render the page with template builder, could see the markup.

Have installed session enabled content service and preview web service, also registered these capabilities in discovery service. Also re-imported the default templates as per the [post](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/why-are-my-tcdl-tags-not-converted-to-xpm-markup) I'm not sure what I'm missing. Appreciate your inputs!

Comment: When you said that "the markup is not appearing on the published pages" do you mean in the file itself, or in the browser. Have you check the visibility between the application and the content manager? (in case these are different machines)

Comment: Markup is not appearing on the file itself. Both application and CM are in the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have re-imported upgraded TBB's as per [post](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3814/908), however I had 2 set of template building blocks, missed out one set at first, re-importing both set of default template's resolved the reported issue.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the problem seems to be with template building blocks (TBBs). Can you please verify that you are not using RenderMode in TBBs to render XPM tags.

For **template builder the RenderMode is PreviewDynamic** and for **Publish transaction, RenderMode is Publish**.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, @Hiren! I'm just using out of the box TBB's, not changing render mode in default TBB's.